# Magento 2: Web Setup Wizard error Setup 401 Unauthorized Access

Tags: magento2, web-setup-wizard

My Magento version is 2.2.3

When i open web setup wizard from admin

It gives error like

> Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters. To use the
>   Magento setup wizard sign into your Admin account and navigate to
>   System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard

http://prntscr.com/johlaz

ill try all the solution but not getting success.

Comment: you can follow this issue on github, like here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12608

Comment: not get the solution